# OPC-plug-in for OpenAPC software?

Tags: opc, scada, process-control

Does anybody know of a 3rd party OPC-plug-in for free OpenAPC-software ( http://www.openapc.com )?

Or in case it does not exist, any recommendations for an open-source OPC client that can be used as base for implementing such a plug-in? Together with their OpenSDK it should be possible easily to implement that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://openopc.sourceforge.net/ is the open source version. But for Python, and is one of the very few proper open source OPCs.

Keep in mind that open source is not free as in beer.
That you can download it for freet does not mean that you will save money. Costs of software are just a part of the total costs. How about sustainability of your project? Do these software packages still exist in about 5 years? OpenAPC is already dead for three years. How will you give support when a big bug has been found?

You have the freedom to change and contribute in the project. But is that a good thing in this current state?

Comment: Why do you think OpenAPC is dead? A new software version was released just some weeks ago and their support is very resonsive.